# Short and long positions of call options

Tags: finance, economics

[image]

I am on part c), and I want to know:

Since I am the seller of this call option, I sold it for 0.44, and the option is worth 1 dollar at expiration. Assuming the buyer wants to make profit he will exercise this option to receive the stock worth 19 dollars (he makes a profit of 56 cents.) what does this mean for me?

Answer (score 1):

That means you have to hedge your option using the underlying stock and cash. If you correctly hedge at the time of the sale, it is irrelevant what the price will be at expiration. But what portfolio do you need to acquire to hedge the option properly?

**EDIT** *Hedging* an instrument (e.g. hedging an option) means acquiring a portfolio which exactly reproduces the payoff of that instrument in all market conditions. This is also sometimes called *replicating* and the resulting portfolio is called the *replicating portfolio*.

Then, the arbitrage-free price of the instrument becomes the price of the replicating portfolio.

Comment: what does "hedge" mean?

Comment: @terribleatmath edited

Comment: so many terms to understand.. this is the difficulty of this area of math.

as the writer of the stock, does this mean I also have the ability to distribute the stocks, so i can make money off of them?

Im familair with the buyer position but not the seller. I also dont know what you mean by "portfolio do you need to acquire"

Comment: my book says this:

http://gyazo.com/93d9e32e49e395afb0ceba7934ac0f49.png

why the heck would you ever write  a call option then, if your max payoff is 0?

Comment: The most common reason to do something you don't want to do: someone pays you to do it

Comment: Well you wouldn't write one for free, the idea is that you sell this option.

Comment: @KaiSikorski okay, so in this scenario i've sold the option for the strike price + the start price, 18.44. what kind of loss/profit can i make at expiration?

Comment: No, the question says the price of the call is just $0.44. Why would anyone buy a call for more than the price of an asset? The answear you were given is right, that the seller of the call should create a replicating portfolio. Your book/ class should certainly explain this in more detail.

Comment: well it doesnt. what the heck is a "portfolio" anyway

Comment: @terribleatmath *portfolio* is a collection of assets. The main idea you should've seen in your class is that you can value complex assets, like call options, using a combination (also called portfolio) of cash and the underlying stock. This is done using a strategy called *replication*.

Comment: @terribleatmath there is a distinction between a *payoff* and *profit*. A *payoff* is the net flow of money *at a given time*. That means a payoff at expiration can be zero, but you get a payment initially if you write the option. A profit diagram is a vertical shift of a payoff diagram.